# kendo ui combo box not sending requests

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-combobox, kendo-ui-mvc

I'm trying to get a Kendo UI combo box to load data from the server as I type. #Client is an Input box. I need the id of the item in the textbox saved, which is why I am using a combo box instead of autocomplete. When I type into the combo box it always sends the string that is 1 keypress behind the data in the input box. I assume this happens because the "shadowed" Kendo UI input box doesn't update the original input box until after the call to the server is already made.

Also, If I don't use the parameterMap code, nothing that is typed in the input box is sent to the server. And, I would expect that the filter condition would be sent too. I have looked at the examples on Telriks site and they show to use the filters from the request parameters to see the data, but when I use fiddler or any other tracing tool, I can see that nothing is sent in the request that has anything to do with the data from the Kendo UI server call. This should be a relativity easy thing to do, but I'm stumped.

EDIT: I changed it to a kendoAutoComplete and everything works as I would expect an AutoComplete to work. It shouldn't be any different than the ComboBox for implementation other than the return for the dataValueField.

```
        $("#Client").kendoComboBox({
            dataTextField: "label",
            displayValueField: "id",
            suggest: true,
            autoBind: false,
            minLength: 1,
            highlightFirst: true,
            filter: "contains",
            dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                serverFiltering: true,
                transport: {
                    read: { url: "/search/client", dataType: "json", type: "POST" },
                    parameterMap: function (data) {
                        return { search: $("#Client").val() }
                    }
                }
            })
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#Client").kendoComboBox({
        dataTextField: "label",
        displayValueField: "id",
        suggest: true,
        autoBind: false,
        minLength: 1,
        highlightFirst: true,
        filter: "contains",
        dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
                read: {
                   url: "/search/client", 
                   dataType: "json", 
                   type: "GET",
                   data: function () {
                     return { search: $("#Client").val() }
                   }
                }
            }
        })
    });
```